# (Strong) causality condition

Tags: general-relativity, semi-riemannian-geometry

I'm studying the causality in Lorentz Manifold with the book "Semi-Riemann Geometry", B.O'Neill. I have the followig problem:
He says that, picked a subset A of a Lorentzian Manifold M, the causality condition hold on A if there aren't closed causal curve in A. After this he proves that if a set is compact it contains a closed causal curve. Then, if I understand, in a compact set the causality condition can't hold. But after this definition, the author proves a lemma in which he supposes that in a compact subset $K \subset M$ the causality condition holds. How can it be possible??

Comment: What he proves is not that a compact set has closed causal curves, but that a compact space-time has closed causal curves. Take Mikowski space-time and a compact subset, it will not have closed causal curves.

Comment: Interesting!! but the Definition of spacetime is just p.163 "connected time-oriented four-dimensional Lorentz manifold" and so why is a compact subset of the Minkowski space no a spacetime? (e.g. a 4 dimensional ball, in the associated euclidian metric)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No closed casual curves $\implies$ Causality condition holds
**Is equivalent to**
Causality condition does not hold $\implies$   a closed casual curve exists

**Not equivalent to**
Closed casual curve exist $\color{red}\implies$ Causality condition doesn't hold

**In your problem**
A is compact $\implies$ a closed casual curve exists
this last condition does not imply that "Causality condition doesn't hold"

Comment: I answered it only by logic, i am not expert in that topic

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see the implication in another way:\\ Causality condition holds implies no closed causal curves. So closed causal curves implies causal condition doesn't hold...

Comment: So, in a compact, a closed causal curve esxists then the causality condition can't hold...It is wrong for you?

Comment: It is not necessarily that "Causality condition doesn't hold"

Comment: I mean that the existence of a closed casual curve is not enough to ensure that "Causality condition doesn't hold"

Comment: ok. thank you so much!!

Comment: The "if" in " If M contains no closed timelike curves, we say that the chronology condition holds on M" (same for causality) Semi-Riemannian geometry p.407, is a definition "if", not an implication. For me the question is still unanswered but the comment by MBN is exactly to the point

Comment: i.e. not just an implication but an equivalence

Answer (score 0):

A compact subset and a compact manifold are different. There must be a point outside the compact subset with the causality condition, but a compact manifold has no this property and this is a key point in the proof of Lemma 14.10.